# Different in google chrome and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, knockout.js, requirejs

My application uses knockout.js custom elements. The load sequence of the viewmodel and template are different in google chrome and internet explorer.

In my web application I have defined a number of custom elements like:

```
   ko.components.register('account-management-me', {
        viewModel: {  require: 'Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/ViewModel' },
        template: { require: 'text!Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/' + language + 'View.html' }
    });
```

With Internet Explorer I observed the following load sequence:

> 1. ViewModel.js
> 2. enView.html

With Chrome I observed the following load sequence:

> 1. enView.html
> 2. ViewModel.js

Hence fields bound in the view from the `ViewModel.js` are undefined and an exception is thrown by knockout.

Is there a way to influence the load order?

Comment: Assuming you have server data returned and then your view model is bound and html is created (ideally speaking), you can wrap your html template inside of `<!--ko if: ifDataPresent() -->` wrapper and it will not build your template html untill `ifDataPresent` observable has a boolean `true` value either coming from the server or assigned manually after your data has been fetched and good to go for binding.....

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to influence the load order?

Yes, if you register your component as a single module, [as shown in the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#registering-components-as-a-single-amd-module), then you can make it so that your view model is dependent on your template and so your template will always be loaded before your view model.

Knockout is using RequireJS to load the view model and the template. As explained in the documentation, it issues a plain `require` call with the module names you to `ko.components.register`. For your code, the equivalent `require` calls would be:

```
require(['Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/ViewModel'], callback);
require(['text!Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/enView.html', callback);
```

These two calls *cannot* constrain the load order. It does not matter that `.../ViewModel` is first. (Actually, it could be second.) Both calls are asynchronous and can resolve in any order *unless* the modules use `define` to establish a dependency of one on the other. This is just how RequireJS works. Without an explicit dependency, the order is indeterminate and can vary due to browser internals, network conditions, etc.

To register your component as a single module, you'd do:

```
ko.components.register('account-management-me', 
  { require: 'Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/ViewModel' });
```

And the module referred above would contain something like:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!Scripts/app/components/accountManagementMe/enView.html'], function(ko, template) {
    function ViewModel() {
    }

    ViewModel.prototype.foo = function() { ... };

    return { viewModel: ViewModel, template: template };
});
```

In this example, I've made the template module name static string. You want to load different templates depending on the configured language but putting strings computed at run time in the dependencies of a `define` is not supported. You can make it work for some trivial cases but if you want to optimize your modules with `r.js`, it will choke on computed strings. To get support for languages, you should use the [`i18n` plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/i18n). Or something that provides similar functionality. There are a lot of questions on SO on how to use it which you can look at if you run into trouble setting up i18n.

Comment: can you please also provide some explanation on why should there be such differences in load order on different browsers? thanks...

Comment: Edited. See the paragraph that begins with "Knockout is using RequireJS to load [...]"